# Put multiple markers in Google maps. Swift

Tags: swift, google-maps, marker

I've number of latitude and longitude in array. I want to display multiple markers in google map. I'm getting proble on that. Here's my code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewMap: UIView!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var mapView = GMSMapView()
var cameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition()


fileprivate func loadData() {
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    showCurrentLocationOnMap()
}

func showCurrentLocationOnMap(){
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        for data in nearByPlacesArray!{
            let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (data.latitude)!, longitude: (data.longitude)!, zoom: 14.0)
            mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.viewMap.frame.size.width, height: self.viewMap.frame.size.height), camera: camera)
            let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: data.latitude!, longitude: data.longitude!)
            print("location: \(location)")
            let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.position = location
            marker.snippet = data.name!
            marker.map = mapView
        }
        self.viewMap.addSubview(mapView)   
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    self.showCurrentLocationOnMap()
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

I am unable to show multiple markers in mapview with this code. There is only one marker displayed in map related to last index of array. Please someone help me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to `addSubview(mapView)` to view before creating markers.

```
var mapView: GMSMapView!

func showCurrentLocationOnMap(){
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 11.11, longitude: 12.12, zoom: 14.0) //Set default lat and long
    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.viewMap.frame.size.width, height: self.viewMap.frame.size.height), camera: camera)
    self.viewMap.addSubview(mapView)   
    for data in nearByPlacesArray!{
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: data.latitude!, longitude: data.longitude!)
        print("location: \(location)")
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = location
        marker.snippet = data.name!
        marker.map = mapView
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    self.showCurrentLocationOnMap()
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: @ Sid Mhatre Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

this is the code for 1 one marker, right?:

```
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView
```

This code above show multiple markers:

```
for marker in 1...5 {

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.96, longitude: 151.20)
        marker.title = "Jow Loove"
        marker.snippet = "California"
        marker.map = mapView

        print ("Your GMSMarker")
        print (marker)

    }
```

**Print a simple marker after loop to see work!**

But you be implement lat, long, title and snipped from some data / variable.

Yes, i lost a biggest time looking for one way to implement dynamic var...

```
var marker1 = 
var marker2 = 
var marker3 = 
....
```

If you now how make it with swift, please, implement the post.

:-)

Answer (score 0):

**in swift 5, You can use**

```
for x in mylocationsArr {
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(x.lat, x.lon)
    marker.title = x.description
    marker.map = self.googleMap        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//you can fill nearByPlacesArray

nearByPlacesArray = ["lat:":"23.898988",Long:"72.898988"]

// you can add multiple lat and long in  nearByPlacesArray this array.

for data in nearByPlacesArray{
        
        let lat = Double(data.Latitude)
        let long = Double(data.Longitude)
        
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:lat!, longitude:long!)
        print("location1: \(location)")
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = location
        //  marker.snippet = data.name
        marker.map = mapView
        marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with:.black)
        marker.icon = UIImage(named: "Location_Icon")
        
        
        
        
    }
```