# Multiple markers are not plotted on google maps in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am plotting multiple custom-view marker on google maps in an iOS swift project but sometimes they are not visible. But when I tap on google maps, the tappable action is called. This means the data is available, but some marker is not plotted or not visible.

I am using the below code:

```swift
for oldSites in self.marrPlotedMarker {
    let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: tempSite["lat"].double ?? 0, longitude: tempSite["lon"].double ?? 0)
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.tracksViewChanges = false
    marker.iconView = mycustoumview()
    marker.position = position
    //marker.isFlat = true
    marker.map = self.myMapview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet doesn't paint the whole picture, but I'm guessing you need to add `self.myMapView` as a subview before creating the markers:

So your code would look something like this:

```swift
self.addSubview(self.myMapView) // important piece
for oldSites in self.marrPlotedMarker {
    let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: tempSite["lat"].double ?? 0, longitude: tempSite["lon"].double ?? 0)
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.tracksViewChanges = false
    marker.iconView = mycustoumview()
    marker.position = position
    //marker.isFlat = true
    marker.map = self.myMapview
}
```

See this post for a similar question/answer: [Put multiple markers in Google maps. Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258862/put-multiple-markers-in-google-maps-swift)

Comment: Thanks, but I have already added this.As I said only some marker is not plotted when I plot second time but when I click on location tap event is working but marker is not visible.

Comment: Can you add more of your code to the question? It's not clear exactly what you're doing and what the issue is.